# From one-dimensional to two-dimensional Markov chains

Tags: markov-chains, queueing-theory

I have a $M/M/1$ queueing system that is described below:

- There are two types of customers in the system with different arrival
  rates, $\lambda_{sg}$ and $\lambda_{sb}$.
- Service rate is $\mu$.
- Type $sg$ customers abandon the queue if waiting time exceeds the
  patience time $\tau$.
- Patience time is exponentially distributed with rate $\xi=\frac{1}{\tau}$.

To model this system, first I tried one-dimensional Markov chains. You can find the chain in the following image:

[image: One-dimensional<code>enter preformatted text here</code>]

However, since only type $sg$ customers abandon the queue, it is better to use two-dimensional Markov chains to model the system.

Following Markov chain is my first try, but it is not true.

[image: Two-dimensional]

The reason is that this two-dimensional Markov chain considers two different queue for two different customers. However there is only one queue for both customers.

The question is:

How to revise this chain to model the system defined above?

Thanks.

Comment: How does service work in this queueing system? Is it like the regular M/M/1 queue where only the first customer is experiencing service and subsequent customers are served in the order in which they arrived (skipping any customers whose patience expired and who left the queue)?

If that is the case then your model state needs to include more information, not just how many customers of each type you have in the queue, but also their position. Once a customer reaches the front of the queue its service rate will depend on what type of customer it is.

Comment: Hi. Actually I ended up with the same thing. Order of the customers also matters and it makes the problem very complicated. So is it possible to model it with Markov chains?

Comment: I can't see an elegant way to describe the state space of the problem. You could make an approximation using processor sharing discipline rather than first come first served and then the problem can be described using a two dimensional state space as you have above.

Comment: I searched a little bit about processor sharing queues. In fact there is no queue such systems. An arrived customer gets the service immediately. Would you give me some key ideas how to implement this to my problem? In particular I couldn't figure out how to select the correct service time? Thank you for time.

Comment: Processor sharing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_sharing) is when the service capacity of the system ($\mu$) is shared between all of the jobs in the queue, rather than being focussed just on the first customer as in first-come first-served (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-come,_first-served)

Comment: So I believe using $\frac{\mu}{i+j}$ instead of $\mu$ in the above 2D chain would work.

Comment: Yes, but you have $(i+j)$ customers each being served at rate $\frac{\mu}{i+j}$. So the system moves from state $(i,j)$ to $(i-1,j)$ at rate $\frac{i\mu}{i+j}+i\xi$ and to state $(i,j-1)$ at rate $\frac{j\mu}{i+j}$. You should be able to figure out the remaining rates.

Comment: Hi. You mention about making an approximation using processor sharing discipline. Would you recommend me an academic paper that shows processor sharing discipline is an approximation to FIFO discipline in M/M/1 queueing system?

Comment: PS isn't an approximation for FIFO. My intention was to suggest a version of the problem which mathematically was easier to tackle.